# Jquery replace inner div with another

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to replace an nested div with a new div.

```
html_string= "<div id='container'><div id='inner'></div></div>";

var newHtml = $(html_string).find("div#inner").replaceWith("<div>NEW CONTENT</div>").html();

console.log('new html is');
console.log(newHtml);
console.log('html_string is');
console.log(html_string);
```

However I get an output of

```
new html is

html_string is 
<div id='container'><div id='inner'></div></div>
```

It doesnt get replaced...

Comment: Get rid of that `.html()` at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
html_string= "<div id='container'><div id='inner'></div></div>";

var newHtml = $(html_string).find("div#inner").replaceWith("<div>NEW CONTENT</div>").end().get(0).outerHTML;

console.log('new html is');
console.log(newHtml);
console.log('html_string is');
console.log(html_string);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Rwv8V/)

Answer (score 0):

break it up a little:

```
html_string = "<div id='container'><div id='inner'></div></div>";
var newHtml = $(html_string)
newHtml.find("div#inner").replaceWith("<div>NEW CONTENT</div>");

console.log('new html is:' + $(newHtml)[0].innerHTML);
console.log('html_string is' + $(html_string)[0].innerHTML);
```

Notice that 
 - html_string IS a string and remains unchanged.
 - newHtml is a jQuery object and gets changed.

Outputs

```
>  new html is:<div>NEW CONTENT</div>
>  html_string is<div> id="inner"></div>
```